# Cordova resume application and angular $apply() on PhoneGap app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, apply, resume

I have Cordova/Ionic/AngularJS application I am currently testing using the PhoneGap app on iOS. This application uses WebSockets to receive external inbound messages. An Angular service function pushes the new messages in an array and binds the array to a scope. I then use `$rootScope.$apply()` to propagate the change to my view that displays this array of messages.

Everything works fine except when I pause and resume the application. In that case, any new incoming message is indeed correctly stored in the messages array however the view is not updated as I would expect from `$apply()`. Leaving the view and returning to it fixes the problem. It's as if reloading the view's controller and calling the service resets something.

Comment: Do you have a code example? Why do you call apply if you're already inside Angular context?